# Redirct to jsp file after http request

Tags: java, jsp

I want to redirect to a jsp file in doPost, my jsp file location

```
-WEB-INF
---jsp
-----transaction.jsp
```

And `doPost`:

```
String path = getContecxFile(m_TRANSACTION_JSP);
try {
    response.sendRedirect(path);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    MLogger.error("fali to init transaction", m_className);
}
```

getting the file path with - `GetContextFile`:

```
private String getContecxFile(String jsp) {
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    String fullPath = context
            .getRealPath("/WEB-INF/jsp/" + jsp);

    return fullPath;
}
```

The path for the file is  `http://someDomainIcantShow.com/usr/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/installedApps/appID/ServletsPEAR.ear/ServletsP.war/WEB-INF/jsp/Transaction.jsp`
as expected but I still get the `404` error.

Comment: do use want to redirect to jsp inside ear/ServletsP.war?

Comment: No, that is my problem.

Comment: why don't you use response.sendRedirect(jsp)?

Answer (score 0):

So I used `RequestDispatcher` to redircet using `forward` method.